# Python C/C++ APIでKeyboardInterruptで処理を停止できない

Tags: python, c++, c

Python C/C++ APIで下記のようにforで0から引数としてとった整数までを表示させる物を書いているのですが、Ctrl-Cを押しても割り込んで処理を停止させることができません。
9999999まで表示した後でKeyboardInterruptが出てしまいます。
どうすればいいのでしょうか?
ちなみにコンパイルは`python3 setup.py build_ext -i`でやっています。

環境はOS X 10.10, Python3.4.3です

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject*
for_int(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int x;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &x))
        return NULL;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;

}

static PyMethodDef For_INT_Methods[] = {
    {"for_int", for_int, METH_VARARGS,
     "fast increment print"}, 
    {NULL, NULL, 0 , NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef for_int_module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "for_int",
    "spam_doc_string",
    -1,
    For_INT_Methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_for_int(void)
{
    PyObject *m;

    m = PyModule_Create(&for_int_module);
    if (m == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Py_INCREF(PyExc_KeyboardInterrupt);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "InterruptError", PyExc_KeyboardInterrupt);
    return m;
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("for_int", PyInit_for_int);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("for_int");
}
```

コンパイルするためのsetup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
module = Extension('for_int', ['for.cpp'])
setup(name='for',
    version='1.0',
    ext_modules=[module],
)
```

**追記**
forの部分でPyErr_CheckSignals()を呼び出すようにしました(code2)
しかし、Ctrl-Cを押しても処理は止まりませんでした。

code2

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        PyErr_CheckSignals(); # 追加
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Mac OSXで試したところ、うまく動きましたよ。コードの内容からしてPython3ですよね？

Comment: はい、このコードはPython3想定です。

Ctrl-Cを押したら、すぐに割り込んで処理を止めて欲しいのですが、
今の状態だと最後まで処理を行ってからKeyboardInterruptが出てしまいます。どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: こちらで試す限り、KeyboardInterruptで途中で止まります。環境によって違うのかもしれません。

Comment: こちらの環境やその他の情報について追記しました。

Comment: コンソールから iterm2を開いて実行したら途中で止められました。sshでログインして実行したら止められませんでした。何かが違うようです。どちらも`SIGINT`を受け取っているので割り込みがマスクされているわけではないですね。シェルの環境なのか、ハードウェア的な何かなのか、スレッドなのか、考え中。

Comment: Linuxでも止まらないですね。

Comment: PyErr_CheckSignals() を時々呼ぶ必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: PyErr_CheckSignals()をforのなかで呼び出すようにしてみましたがうまく止まりませんでした。(追記参照)
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: google で探して見つけただけなので、詳しくは解りません。すみません。ただ、`int s = PyErr_CheckSignals(); if (s != 0) { Py_INCREF(Py_None); return Py_None; }` といった感じに使うと挙動が変わると思います。この先どうすればいいのかは、私には解りませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[例外処理 —— Python 3.4.3ドキュメント](http://docs.python.jp/3/c-api/exceptions.html) によると (強調は引用者による)、

> ある関数が呼び出した関数がいくつか失敗したために、その関数が失敗しなければならないとき、一般的にエラーインジケータを設定しません。呼び出した関数がすでに設定しています。**エラーを処理して例外をクリアするか、あるいは(オブジェクト参照またはメモリ割り当てのような)それが持つどんなリソースも取り除いた後に戻るかのどちらか一方を行う責任があります。エラーを処理する準備をしていなければ、普通に続けるべきではありません。** エラーのために戻る場合は、エラーが設定されていると呼び出し元に知らせることが大切です。エラーが処理されていない場合または丁寧に伝えられている場合には、 Python/C APIのさらなる呼び出しは意図した通りには動かない可能性があり、不可解な形で失敗するかもしれません。

(最後の一文、「エラーが処理されていなかったり、注意深く伝搬されていなかったりした場合には」の誤訳だと思う -- 閑話休題)

とのことなので、エラーを検知した場合、それを関数内で処理し切ってしまうか、あるいは処理を中止してエラーを伝搬させるかを、関数自身の責任で行わなければなりません。
シグナル発生時に中断したいならば、@masm さんがコメントで指摘されているように、 `PyErr_CheckSignals()` でシグナル発生をチェックした上で、発生していたらそこで中断するようにします。
`for_int()` の定義で、 `PyArg_ParseTuple()` が失敗したら `NULL` を返すようになっていますが、これと同様、`PyErr_CheckSignals()` がシグナルの発生を検知したら、`NULL` を返して終了するようにします。必要に応じてリソースの解放を行う必要もありますが、今回は不要ですね。

```cpp
static PyObject*
for_int(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int x;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &x))
        return NULL;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        // シグナルの発生を調べ、発生していたら中断する。
        if (PyErr_CheckSignals() != 0) {
            return NULL;
        }
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;

}
```

Comment: 手元で動きました。逆にMacでコンソールから起動したときにブレークできるのはどうしてなんでしょうね....。